# Not able to access input text value using blur event

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have what I thought was a straight forward task.
I have a Primefaces p:inputText field that I need to use after I navigate out of that field.  I am using p:ajax event="blur" to initiate the backing bean processing.  That seems to work OK, but when I look at the value that should be in the inputText field, it is coming back as null in the backing bean.

Here is the code I have: Input text component:

```
<p:inputText id="redirectionDocIdInput" size="21" 
             rendered="#{!isInquiryMode}"
             onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"
             value="#{redirectionForm.redirectDocId}" >
     <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{redirectionController.findRedirectDocFromId(redirectionForm)}" 
             update=":tabView:redirectionForm:redirectionMessages :#{p:component('authDocLaInput')}" />
</p:inputText>
```

And here is the backing bean:

```
public void findRedirectDocFromId( RedirectionForm form ) {
    String docId = form.getRedirectDocId();
    Document redirDoc = searchService.getDocumentByDocumentId(docId);
    if( redirDoc == null ) {
        MessageUtils.addFacesErrorMessage("Document Id ("+docId+") not found.");
        return;
    }
    form.setRedirectDoc(redirDoc);
    form.setAuthDocLA(redirDoc.getLandAreaCode());
    form.setRedirectDocId(docId);
}
```

I can set a break point in the backing bean and I see a valid component value for the form, but the redirectDocId is coming back null.
What am I doing wrong, or what do I need to add?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please read [ask] and [mcve] and http:www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and improve your post accordingly

Comment: Remove `rendered="#{!isInquiryMode}"` as test. Does it start to work?